# plotting mutation-signatures using plot.py -matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

let me start this conversation with a saying that 
i am a Life science student and has a very limited knowledge of codes/coding
I am a non native English speaker- please pardon me for bad sentences.

Now the point is, i am trying to plot few mutation signature and followed the protocol mentioned in [https://github.com/mskcc/mutation-signatures][1]
I ran the codes and worked perfectly file with small tweekings here and their. 
Now the problem: I am not able to plot the graph using the code provided. I tried to run the codes, the code execute without any error but no graph gets generated. the codes are as follows.

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_signature(array, ylim=0.2, ax=None):
    color = ((0.196,0.714,0.863),)*16 + ((0.102,0.098,0.098),)*16 + ((0.816,0.180,0.192),)*16 + ((0.777,0.773,0.757),)*16 + ((0.604,0.777,0.408),)*16 + ((0.902,0.765,0.737),)*16
    color = list(color)

    width = max(array.shape)
    x = np.arange(width)
    if ax == None:
        f,ax = plt.subplots(1)
    bars = ax.bar(x, array)
    for h in range(len(x)):
        bars[h].set_color(color[h])
    plt.ylim(0, ylim)
    plt.xlim(0, width)
```

My input file for - it contains ~ 90,000 rows and 32 col. I am pasting few lines for reference.

```
Sample Name Number of Mutations Signature.1 Signature.2 Signature.3 Signature.4 Signature.5 Signature.6 Signature.7 Signature.8 Signature.9 Signature.10    Signature.11    Signature.12    Signature.13    Signature.14    Signature.15    Signature.16    Signature.17    Signature.18    Signature.19    Signature.20    Signature.21    Signature.22    Signature.23    Signature.24    Signature.25    Signature.26    Signature.27    Signature.28    Signature.29    Signature.30
SA514594:364    36  7.78592192065E-08   2.097572072E-09 0.0129577423    9.20111534665E-06   1.29424962826E-07   1.98005511129E-08   1.26984775615E-06   0.3514290588    0.0372716931    0.0958290482    0.2914266043    0.0476294564    4.51267691498E-09   3.55645496695E-13   4.6695834626E-09    0.000000545 5.13574031772E-08   0.0186529253    1.8201302324E-06    0.043052409 2.39857754203E-09   0.1017104288    2.21024941929E-05   3.73820687618E-08   0.000005183 5.20135467223E-10   5.75255021998E-11   1.76294823447E-07   4.98920127768E-10   5.34103299834E-09
SA563521:989    10  7.49965977247E-10   4.13113346181E-10   1.0099299403E-08    4.43839791749E-09   1.89175741399E-08   4.73687009296E-07   7.93698793911E-08   1.50060488095E-07   1.60407377105E-14   2.2402869059E-09    2.57703464824E-07   3.39152608647E-08   4.73816059109E-10   1.30132918254E-07   0.1532953333    3.37378315514E-13   3.73480840782E-11   3.92305145877E-08   1.06057853479E-07   3.75366032358E-08   5.18297210275E-09   9.21938160795E-10   0.8467032798    1.95047798186E-08   7.9503285236E-10    9.6820400312E-09    8.52632390449E-10   2.5569616271E-09    8.89791176346E-12   2.33257971361E-09
SA563521:988    12  2.01408694868E-13   6.94970409068E-17   1.04051888263E-17   4.03035700807E-15   1.53337298887E-10   2.71673574926E-10   2.72550219835E-12   8.11473820658E-15   3.49817328528E-15   0.3039159534    7.35153869281E-11   6.66747401284E-17   2.0223426812E-14    2.37769345495E-12   0.1443167244    4.54170429018E-09   5.25265000111E-10   1.69686184791E-11   1.46467223749E-09   3.63439123157E-10   2.2286664556E-14    2.46092931322E-14   0.5517673123    1.70627447502E-14   2.33903853883E-14   0   1.91451197912E-10   1.67714894501E-09   5.65514969383E-12   5.81841472666E-10
SA514594:748    32  4.39048824824E-10   0.1387149347    2.63250457482E-08   2.04827330493E-07   2.53105675374E-07   2.16032982013E-09   0.0689924644    5.87670361308E-07   0.000000016 0.0275933627    0.0139003487    1.87482589409E-05   6.61001874785E-11   1.70197660168E-07   6.24545993006E-12   8.44220707558E-08   0.1782440807    0.0370214957    2.05063671295E-09   0.214294297 1.76981476464E-09   0.2051636458    0.077341418 0.0387127344    2.94681726673E-09   2.19703001755E-10   1.91011492539E-09   4.57432152395E-07   4.34928363931E-07   2.23228697236E-07
SA563521:985    12  4.99026110498E-16   8.13032541388E-18   2.72930182679E-11   5.31794750754E-11   0   8.61526829988E-16   1.01967064621E-11   0   1.85442216805E-11   0.6242673449    1.02554778517E-11   7.23691520976E-18   0   4.1763626918E-17    5.4482878726E-19    0   1.05636530056E-14   6.79607466904E-12   5.20132496759E-14   1.09829541945E-10   0   0   0.3757326548    0   5.81925051141E-11   0   6.54043368948E-13   3.94124358229E-11   0   0
SA563521:984    11  1.06852440641E-09   1.45841022194E-09   1.84012279811E-10   8.8238612536E-10    3.29678919073E-10   1.07130936804E-09   0.3500807401    8.08485800331E-10   2.38453374497E-09   0.1908697612    2.2226639135E-06    1.73861711501E-09   3.50621076051E-10   4.61772309668E-10   2.17226011174E-11   1.89077430359E-09   0.000000004 2.53608272626E-10   2.69735968532E-09   2.5590749113E-10    1.77651552028E-09   9.85386735785E-13   0.4590464389    1.71234635886E-10   3.12090895916E-10   2.03246422179E-10   6.90032248044E-10   1.16551785864E-08   6.47778745925E-09   0.000000796
SA563521:987    8   1.39902397714E-12   3.64773172907E-13   1.2398655225E-13    4.03530900677E-13   2.70474137971E-12   8.47359618869E-11   8.92578609262E-10   2.25128705083E-11   3.15717498019E-13   0.2956488095    0.3279487777    6.09808916281E-14   1.32870210616E-13   5.37394770341E-11   0.1606784188    1.43388151764E-13   1.4190492595E-14    3.00217629895E-12   5.59184687814E-12   3.69879139456E-12   5.50989714204E-11   5.5602072094E-15    0.2157239928    2.73447270304E-12   2.2565665674E-11    7.07371234887E-12   1.25469736835E-13   4.32396081812E-15   9.18476181781E-13   1.32854279215E-14
```

It would be really helpful for me if you guys help me in plotting this. I am attaching the input file for your reference `https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4EniZCsdQJ5RFVtLVBqdklrTEU`

Comment: If you run this as a script you need to tell matplotlib to actually show the plot, `plt.show()`.

Comment: i tried plt.show() and also plt.plot(output.jpg), but still no output. I actually need to know how to pass my input csv file to the function as an array.

Comment: Ah, ok that wasn't clear from the question. You would probably like to convert your ods file to csv format first, then read it in with `numpy.genfromtxt` or `pandas.read_csv`. It's not clear to me what the barplot should show (one row of the file, or one column, or all data, but then which axis should be which?).

Comment: I am looking for a graph as in this link : https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/core/lw/2.0/html/tileshop_pmc/tileshop_pmc_inline.html?title=Click%20on%20image%20to%20zoom&p=PMC3&id=3607224_fx1.jpg.